# Lift it to travel through time

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I came up with this riddle on the train home from work. After seeing what your puzzle fiends crack on a daily basis, I'll be lucky if it survives a single read-through, but I suppose it'll do for a first submission.

> Easy to judge, for better or worse,
>  While others will take some
>   time and discourse.
>
> Looks foreign and strange without the aid,
>  Either theirs or yours,
>   will be naked or fade.
>
> Scaled up, rarely down - the risk is too great.
>  Look at its hands,
>   before it's too late!
>
> Would grant you your whims if made into a book,
>  And hides in plain
>   sight wherever you look.

Hint #1:

> A relevant deity would make an immature teenager giggle. 'cause butt!

Hint #2:

> If I said you had one, you'd think it rather obvious. But if I said you had two, you'd get offended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Face

Lift it to travel through time (title)

> A face-lift makes you look younger.

```
Easy to judge, for better or worse,
While others will take some time and discourse.
```

> Some faces are easy to read, others no so easy. Face time is used to communicate remotely.

```
Looks foreign and strange without the aid,
Either theirs or yours, will be naked or fade.
```

> Without glasses faces look different. If the viewee isn't wearing them, they look naked. If the viewer isn't wearing them then the other person looks blurry or faded.

```
Scaled up, rarely down - the risk is too great.
```

> Rock faces are scaled - it's easier to climb up than down.

```
Look at its hands, before it's too late!
```

> A clock face has hands and tells you the time.

```
Would grant you your whims if made into a book,
And hides in plain sight wherever you look.
```

> Facebook grants whims?
>  Objects everywhere have faces / surfaces.

Hint #1:

> A relevant deity would make an immature teenager giggle. 'cause butt!
>   The god Janus (who has a face looking in each direction) sounds like anus.

Hint #2:

> If I said you had one, you'd think it rather obvious. But if I said you had two, you'd get offended.
>  Everyone has one face, but no-body likes being called two-faced.

*thanks to @Daphne B for a couple of extra hints*

From OP:

```
Easy to judge, for better or worse,
While others will take some time and discourse.
```

> We quickly judge people by their face/appearance when we first meet them, sometimes forming the wrong opinion. To see other aspects of people beyond appearance you need to talk and get to know them.

```
Would grant you your whims if made into a book,
```

> The creator of Facebook, Mark Zuckerberg, became one of the richest people on the planet and can now afford just about anything.

```
And hides in plain sight wherever you look.
```

> We always see the tip of the nose, no matter where we look, but our brain filters it out so we don't notice it.

Comment: I think your answer is right but I think you've missed a clue and the first hint.  If I'm right: hint #1 rhymes with a word that means "butt".  "Look at its hands before it's too late" has its own answer that has nothing to do with the line before it.  (The one you didn't know, I don't know either.)

Comment: Nice! You got the right answer, although some of the lines aren't really what I meant. I'm not sure how to give out hints on these, though. Does the spoiler tag work in comments?

Comment: First two lines - think more like "other aspects" not just "other its".
The one you don't know is fairly literal. Aid is key and is an object.
One of your answers has a question mark. The answer is - "It did for one! And he's the only one it really applies to"
In the same hidden block as the line above, the second line isn't really right. Not specific objects, but always, no matter which direction. With a little FOCUS you could CROSS the barrier and surMOUNT the problem. Ask your brain, he KNOWS, that's why you hid it ;)

Comment: Hey, good job on the one you didn't know! That's exactly right. The others are still off.
I also posted another riddle I wrote this morning after breakfast. If you liked this one, check out my second one.